# Can i limit my result to a specific number in sql?

Tags: mysql

```
Select count(*) as c from casting where ord = 1 Group by actorid Order by count(*) DESC
```

The result is
15 15 14 13 12 10 7 7 7 7 5 5

Then i would like to get the result only greater than 10 ??how to do that thanks~~

Comment: Wow I thought I'll answer that. I do a refresh and 3 answers already! People are hungry!

Comment: Just want to make sure you receive the answer to your second question. Use SELECT SUM(ord = 1) instead of COUNT(ord = 1) . COUNT counts all columns which aren't NULL, and since (ord = 1) either return 1 or 0, it will count all rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT count(*) AS c 
FROM casting 
WHERE ord = 1 
GROUP BY actorid 
HAVING c > 10
ORDER BY c DESC
```

You can consider [`HAVING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) the `WHERE` clause for `GROUP BY` aggregates.

Comment: You might aswell reuse the value instead of counting again: HAVING c > 10 . It's good practice to cut the server some slack.

Comment: @robin didn't think that mysql will count it thrice if you write count(*) in the havign and order clause instead of the alias. Are you sure about that?

Comment: @Robin, if you restate `count(*)` in the having clause, MySQL will not recalculate but use a cached value instead, `having count(*) > 10` is identical to `having c > 10` the latter is just easier to read perhaps.

Comment: if i don't want to show count(*) but i need to grab how many numbers that ord = 1, what can i do???

Comment: seems i can not do count(ord =1) for each actorid directly without count(*)

Comment: every counted one has ord = 1, as that was specified in the where clause. @foodil so count(*) is the number of rows that have ord=1

Comment: @foodil: SELECT SUM(ord = 1) 
Johan: What happens if you run high calculations? Will it cache that aswell? Still think it's good practice to always use existing values, before calcuating the same instead.

Comment: @foodil, if you want to show the total as well as the subtotals, then write: `SELECT count(*) AS c FROM casting WHERE ord = 1 GROUP BY actorid WITH ROLLUP HAVING c > 10 ORDER BY c DESC`, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM casting WHERE ord = 1 GROUP BY actorid HAVING COUNT(*) > 10 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: You might aswell reuse the value instead of counting again: HAVING c > 10 . It's good practice to cut the server some slack.

Comment: +1, never mind Robin's comment, the performance of `having count(*) > 10` is identical to `having c > 10`.

Answer (score 1):

```
HAVING c > 10
```

Place this between group by and order by

Comment: i also wonder whether the order of group by and order by make difference???whether one of them have to come first or not??

Comment: @foodil order by always goes last, but before a limit.

Comment: @foodil, the order matters, one is a syntax error, the other is not :-).